# Shorten block/link text in Drupal's Superfish module

Tags: css, drupal, menu, module, superfish

This question is regarding Drupal 7 and the 'Superfish' addon that allows me to create a menu along the header of the webpage.

I have set it all up and got it working so that the menu appears with links to internal pages of the website, but a couple of links in the menu are fairly long and wondered if it's possible to drop a word beneath another within the same box just so the menu stays on one line rather than going onto a second due to the length.

I can't simply add a br tag as it appears in between the two words in the block rather than actually making a new line for the word. My guess is I will have to make a change to the .css file associated with this module, but help is much appreciated, thank you.

Mike

Comment: Could you provide more information, for ex: a link to your test-site.

Comment: For example, I have a navigation box that says 'profile management' but this is too long and would like the word 'management' to appear below the word 'profile' within the same box so that box is not as wide. But the navigation menu is created in the Superfish module in Drupal so I am limited to how much I can edit this module, but I imagine it's just CSS related which I can access, but not sure what the CSS styling would be to compress a box and move a word ontop of another.

Comment: Well that said, nobody can help you if you don't provide us code, or a link to the test-site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change "css" in the module. Build your own to override module CSS properties.

I assume (since you don't provide code) that you would have to use "width" and/or "height" properties. That supposes that every menu items will have the same look.